# app - Failed to inflate view

Tags: android, xml, layout, logcat

Ive only edited the xml in an app created by the android tools and the app fails to launch and sends me to perspective view and pops up with ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2306

This is the Logcat:

```
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977): Failed to inflate
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #113: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:282)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at com.timmo.tampmusicplayer.NowPlaying.onCreate(NowPlaying.java:12)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    ... 24 more
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1991)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
03-22 20:47:09.865: E/ActivityThread(14977):    ... 27 more
```

Xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#111111"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".NowPlaying" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlcontrols"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bplay"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvalbum"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/play"
        android:contentDescription="@+string/play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bprevious"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvalbum"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bplay"
        android:background="@drawable/previous"
        android:contentDescription="@+string/play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bnext"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvalbum"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bplay"
        android:background="@drawable/next"
        android:contentDescription="@+string/play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/brepeat"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bnext"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bnext"
        android:background="@drawable/repeat"
        android:contentDescription="@+string/play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bshuffle"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bprevious"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bprevious"
        android:background="@drawable/shuffle"
        android:contentDescription="@+string/play" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/bplay"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seeker" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtime"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/songProgressBar"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/time"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvalbum"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/rlcontrols"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/album"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvartist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/tvalbum"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/artist"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvtitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/tvartist"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivalbumart"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/tvtitle"
    android:contentDescription="@+string/albumart"
    android:src="@drawable/albumart" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest if needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.timmo.tampmusicplayer"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.timmo.tampmusicplayer.NowPlaying"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Class just because:

```
public class NowPlaying extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.nowplaying);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.now_playing, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Please someone explain to me what ive done wrong because i have no idea and don't understand this `layoutinflater` or even how to read the Logcat.. thanks for the help

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError this is an hint that you have finished available memory. Most probably you are loading a very large bitmap. how big is @drawable/albumart?

Comment: its 2000x2000 and the rest of most of my drawables are about 1000x1000 is that whats causing it? ill reduce the size

Comment: I experienced comparable problems with large drawables. Try to reduce its dimensions

Comment: oh my god thank you.... i cant believe i did that its been bugging me for days. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a large bitmap file. If you need to support multiple device, I suggest making use of different drawable folders:

- drawable
- drawable-ldpi
- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-xdpi

Android will basically choose which folder to look at, depending on the device. Here's a good reading on this : [Android Doc - Providing the Best Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)